# Postgresql, query to count number of uses of a machine for a particular gender

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by

I have 4 tables

- usages (idus, ..., #idt, #idm)
- machines (idm, namem)
- trainings (idt, ... , #idu)
- users (idu,.., gender)

I want to edit this query (which show how many times a machine was used) to a query that will show how many times a particular gender used this machine.

For example:

```
machine    | male | female
-----------+------+----
treadmill  |  30  |  100
biceps m   | 150  |   22
```

My query:

```
SELECT machines.namem as machine, COUNT(*)
FROM usages, machines
WHERE users.”#idm” = machines.idm 
GROUP BY machines
ORDER BY COUNT DESC;
```

Thanks for all help.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation. From your data structures, it looks like you need to bring the 4 tables in order to get the result that you expect:

```
select 
    m.namem as machine, 
    sum(case when u.gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) male,
    sum(case when u.gender = 'female' then 1 else 0 end) female
from 
    usages s
    inner join machines m on m.idm = s."#idm"
    inner join trainings t on t.idt = s."#idt"
    inner join users u on u.idu = t."#idu"
group by m.namem
order by count(*) desc;
```

Side notes:

- always use explicit joins (with `on` clauses) instead of old-school, implicit joins (with commas in the `from` clause), whose syntax has fallen out of favor very long ago
- your original query has flaws: table `users` is not defined in the query (it is not present in the `from` clause), yet you relate to columns from that table int he `select` and `where` clauses

Comment: Thanks a lot, works very well, also thanks for a tip on how to improve my original query.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
SELECT m.namem as machine, gender, COUNT(*)
FROM usages u 
inner join machines m on u.[#idm]= m.idm 
inner join users uz on uz.idu = u.idus

GROUP BY m.namem, gender
ORDER BY 4  DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT m.namem as machine, COUNT(*),
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE u.gender = 'F') as females,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE u.gender = 'M') as males
FROM usages us JOIN
     machines m
     on us.”#idm” = m.idm JOIN
     users u
     ON us.idu = u.idu
GROUP BY m.namen
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: 'ON us.idu = u.idu' usage does not have 'idu' and users dont have 'idus', I think this must be connected through trainings table.